# Нужна помощь в решении задачи Python

Tags: python, dict

Создай функцию `who_is_online`, которая принимает список словарей `friends` и определяет кто из них `online`, `offline` или `away`. Если у юзера стоит статус `online`, но его не было в сети более 10 минут (`lastActivity > 10`), то можно считать, что его статус отныне `away`.

Пример входящих данных:

```
[{
  "username": "Alice",
  "status": "online",
  "lastActivity": 10
}, {
  "username": "Lucy",
  "status": "offline",
  "lastActivity": 22
}, {
  "username": "Bob",
  "status": "online",
  "lastActivity": 104
}]
```

Результат функции `who_is_online`:

```
{
  "online": ["Alice"],
  "offline": ["Lucy"],
  "away": ["Bob"]
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки реализовать это и с чем возникли сложности?

Answer (score 0):

Задачка лёгкая, тебе стоило еще немного подумать и пробовать различные варианты решения

```py
def who_is_online(lst_friends: list[dict]) -> dict:
    # Создаем словарь, который позже будем возврощать
    result = {
        'online': [],
        'offline': [],
        'away': []
    }

    # Циклом проходимся по всем словарям в списке
    for friend in lst_friends:

        # Теперь сравниваем каждого друга с его статусом
        # И добавляем его в наш словарь result
        if friend['status'] == 'offline':
            result['offline'].append(friend['username'])
        elif friend['lastActivity'] > 10:
            result['away'].append(friend['username'])
        else:
            result['online'].append(friend['username'])

    # Возвращаем наш результат!
    return result
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Может быть подскажите хорошие материалы для изучения словарей и вложенных циклов? Только начинаю обучение, читаю теорию-все понятно, а начинаешь задачи решать-темный лес!

Comment: Порекомендовать не смогу, просто загугли и почитай пару статей, попробуй изменять код, использовать различные значения

Answer (score 0):

```
def who_is_online(friens: list[dict]):
    statuses = {'online': [], 'offline': [], 'away': []}  # Этот словарь будет выводом
    # Перебираем друзей и, исходя из данных, распределяем их по статусам
    for i in friens:
        if (stat := i['status']) == 'offline' or i['status'] == 'away':
            statuses[stat].append(i['username'])
        elif i['lastActivity'] > 10:
            statuses['away'].append(i['username'])
        else:
            statuses['online'].append(i['username'])
    # Удаляем пустые значения
    toDelete = [i for i, j in statuses.items() if not j]
    for i in toDelete:
        del statuses[i]
    return statuses
```

Comment: Если ты используешь type hinting, то используй его везде (укажи, что вернет функция). Просто от того, что ты сделал смысла большого не будет(

Comment: Спасибо большое! А подскажите, еще, пожалуйста, если в некоторых тестовых данных в словаре status es в некоторых ключах оказываются пустые списки, как из этого словаря удалить эти ключи с этими пустыми списками?